# Longest Contiguous sequence Problem

Tags: algorithms

Given 2 strings each of length upto $10^5$ Where String 1 is smaller or equal to length of String 2.Now i need to find longest contiguous sequence common in both the strings.

If their are multiple strings of equal length present i need to find first such string in String 1 .

Example : Say string 1 is "hijefg" and string 2 is "efghij" then here answer will be hij of length 3 as the answer.

Please help to solve this problem in an efficient manner.

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: I don't think the (string-theory) was intended for *this* kind of string...

Comment: @JackM Oh am so sorry i misinterpreted that tag

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** second version

Let $T1(k) = [...(i,t), ..., (j,t)...]$ and $T2(k) = [...(k,t), ..., (l,t)...]$ be lists of substrings from $s1$ and $s2$. $t$ is present at index $i$ and $j$ in $s1$. The lists are ordered by index.

To compute $T1(1)$ and $T2(1)$ is trivial.

To compute other values :

Let $Ti'(2k)$ be the list $[(i,t+t') for (i,t) and (i+k,t') in Ti(k)]$

$T1(2k)$ and $T2(2k)$ are the sublists of $T1'(2k)$ and $T2'(2k)$ reduced to common substrings.

Let $K$ be the last $k$ such as $T1(2^k)$ is not empty.

The searched substring has a length l such $2^K \leq l <2^{K+1}$

From the lists of $\{Ti(2^l)\}$ you can compute $Ti(2^{K+\frac{K}{2}})$, if it is not empty, $2^{K+\frac{K}{2}} \ leq l <2^{K+1}$, else $2^K \leq l<2^{K+\frac{K}{2}}$. etc.

**Complexity**

To build $T1(k+p)$ and $T2(k+p)$ from  $T1(k)$, $T1(p)$, $T2(k)$ and $T2(p)$ can be performed in $O(n*log(n))$

Global complexity is in $O(n*log(n)^2)$

Comment: @Bilouo6 Which in the worst case can go upto O(n*n). So its very insufficient.

Comment: it depends of your constraints. If the strings are randomly generated, it won't be a problem. But I agree, it is possible to do shorter

Comment: @Bilouo6 yeah string length can be very large so i want a efficient algorithm

Comment: Ok, I rewrite it to make faster

Comment: @Bilouo6 You know computing all substrings means having size of array to (n*(n-1)/2) where n is length of string which is impractical for large strings

Comment: I only compute all substrings common to the 2 strings. If they are both "aaaaaaa....aaaa", you will get to $(n*(n-1)/2$ for each list. 

In the case of your example, |T(1)| = 6, |T(2)| = 4, |T(3)| = 2

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem from currently running contest: Codechef March Challenge 2014.
It's disgrace that some people's are asking help for currently running contest.